# Stuck at boot: R8169 can't disable ASPM [Solved]

Tags: boot, networking, drivers, kernel, black-screen

Since kernel 4.15.0.55 update, I'm getting stuck at boot. No kenel after .55 can't boot. At recovery mode system halts at this message:

r8169 can't disable ASPM OS doesn't have ASPM control

I've found this is a long lasting bug. 
I've installed r8168-dkms (8.045.08-2ubuntu1) with synaptic package manager, but I've seen r8168 don't replace r8169, and boot halts at same point.
I've found a forum post pointing to install r8168-dkms_8.047.02-1_all.deb, instead, but I'm not sure about this workaround.

```
    dmesg | grep r816
    [    2.909400] r8169 Gigabit Ethernet driver 2.3LK-NAPI loaded
    [    2.909416] r8169 0000:03:00.2: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
    [    2.910627] r8169 0000:03:00.2 eth0: RTL8402 at 0x        (ptrval), 1c:b7:2c:0f:6a:c8, XID 04000800 IRQ 89
    [    3.050940] r8169 0000:03:00.2 enp3s0f2: renamed from eth0
    [  214.785516] r8169 0000:03:00.2 enp3s0f2: link down
    [ 5487.302121] r8169 0000:03:00.2 enp3s0f2: link down
```

Edit:

Also I've found a solution at github "[Linux driver for Realtek network chips with enabled ASPM](https://github.com/KastB/r8169)", but not tried yet

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I have installed Linux-generic-hwe-18.04, and now I can boot without any problem. It has been solved since kernel 4.19